# Using the Smart phone URL with Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I am developing an application in Rail 3 using the Omniauth gem for Facebook Connect. Currently the gem is using the normal Facebook website for login but I know that Facebook got a specialised website for Smartphones located at `touch.facebook.com`.

Does anyone know how to use the smart phone URL with the Omniauth Gem instead of the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, according to Facebook you just have to pass an additional parameter to the authentication url to get the wap or touch versions of the site: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#web

Have you tried using the :options available in the facebook strategy code linked to by Marcel in the answer above? It looks like it should be pretty simple!

Comment: Hi, yes I tried adding :display => touch to the string in the initializer omniauth.rb but I get this error: auth/failure?message=invalid_credentials. Thanks anyway! Perhaps I am doing it wrong?

Comment: Just an update, I'm using this in my initializer and it works great. The only issue is that you can't have one strategy for desktop and one for mobile, but I just use the touch version for desktop and it looks fine. Just a little more sparse than the regular one.

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan,

The strategy for facebook is **hard coded** to graph.facebook.com => https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/master/oa-oauth/lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook.rb

I suggest to **fork** the project and create something like oa-mobile.

Also, remember they got a **google group** : http://groups.google.com/group/omniauth?pli=1

Regards

Comment: oa-mobile does not exists, it's your contribution to omni auth :)

Comment: I've looked at the google group and haven't found a thing. Maybe you should post there, see what's the omni auth people think about that ?